# Extend make commands

Tags: node.js, makefile, npm

I’m using `make` for front-end development. My issue might be better explained by example. With `npm`, I can have in my `package.json`:

```
"html_dev": "jade --pretty --hierarchy ./src-dir --out ./dev-dir",
"html_watch": "npm run html:dev -- --watch"
```

What this means is that `html_watch` is basically the same as `html_dev` *with the addition of* the `--watch` flag. The benefits are clear: change `html_dev`, and automatically get those changes in `html_watch`.

However, with `make` I’m having no such luck and seem to need to repeat the commands:

```
html_dev:
    jade --pretty --hierarchy ./src-dir --out ./dev-dir
html_watch:
    jade --pretty --hierarchy ./src-dir --out ./dev-dir --watch
```

I can work around this by using variables:

```
htm_dev_command := jade --pretty --hierarchy ./src-dir --out ./dev-dir

html_dev:
    $(html_dev_command)
html_watch:
    $(html_dev_command) --watch
```

This works, but will get ugly fast as I have a bunch commands I’d like to extend.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want [Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) and [Target-specific Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific).

You would use a variable for your command's arguments and then append/prepend to it in the target-specific variables for the `html_watch` target which would then list `html_dev` as its prerequisite.

The recipe for `html_dev` would then just use that variable.

You could also use extensible variables and load variables by target name.

```
common_ARGS := --pretty --hierarchy ./src-dir --out ./dev-dir
html_watch_ARGS := --watch

html_watch html_dev:
    jade $(common_ARGS) $($@_ARGS)
```

Or include `$(common_ARGS)` in the assignment to `html_watch_ARGS` (and also assign `html_dev_ARGS`) and then just use that one variable in the recipe.

Comment: That works, but I’d rather not have to use variables to do it. To me, it’s less readable than having various commands.

Comment: There's no way to avoid that with make that I can think of. If everything just builds off the common arguments you could write a single `html_dev` target with the full command written out with `$(EXTRA_ARGS)` on the end and then use `EXTRA_ARGS := ....` in every extended command if that reads better to you. Does `npm` allow for arbitrary numbers of commands per "target"? If so how does it deal with that and adding arguments? (That's why `make` doesn't have a concise way to do this it won't know where to add the arguments.)